# Remove pattern from database in R

Tags: r, dataset, gsub

Here is my Sample Dataset:

```
 > head(d3)
V1                  V2                       V3                     V4                      V5                     V6
2 Bacteria(100) Proteobacteria(100) Gammaproteobacteria(100)   Pseudomonadales(100)           Pseudomonadaceae(100)    Pseudomonas(98)
3 Bacteria(100)  Bacteroidetes(100)          Bacteroidia(93)      Bacteroidales(93)        unclassified(93)   unclassified(93)
4 Bacteria(100)     Firmicutes(100)             Bacilli(100)   Lactobacillales(100)   Streptococcaceae(100) Streptococcus(100)
5 Bacteria(100) Proteobacteria(100) Gammaproteobacteria(100)    Pasteurellales(100)    Pasteurellaceae(100)   unclassified(68)
6 Bacteria(100) Proteobacteria(100) Gammaproteobacteria(100) Enterobacteriales(100) Enterobacteriaceae(100)   unclassified(90)
7 Bacteria(100)  Bacteroidetes(100)         Bacteroidia(100)     Bacteroidales(100) Porphyromonadaceae(100)  unclassified(100)
```

I'm trying to remove the (100) from each String. 
I've tried:

```
>d3 <- gsub("[(0-9)]", "", d3)
```

Which gives me a mess of a dataset filled with what seems like all the numbers I've tried to remove within `c()` at the bottom. So then I tried this:

```
>for(j in 1:nrow(d3)){

    for(i in 1:ncol(d3)){
       d3[j,i] <- gsub("[(0-9)]", "", as.character(d3[j,i]))
       }
    }
```

which gives me "invalid factor level, NA generated" and also a mess of a dataset with most everything replaced with NA! I couldn't find any questions that were quite what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
d3[] <- sapply(d3,function(x){
  gsub("\\(\\d+\\)","",as.character(x))
})
##
> d3
        V1             V2                  V3                V4                 V5            V6
2 Bacteria Proteobacteria Gammaproteobacteria   Pseudomonadales   Pseudomonadaceae   Pseudomonas
3 Bacteria  Bacteroidetes         Bacteroidia     Bacteroidales       unclassified  unclassified
4 Bacteria     Firmicutes             Bacilli   Lactobacillales   Streptococcaceae Streptococcus
5 Bacteria Proteobacteria Gammaproteobacteria    Pasteurellales    Pasteurellaceae  unclassified
6 Bacteria Proteobacteria Gammaproteobacteria Enterobacteriales Enterobacteriaceae  unclassified
7 Bacteria  Bacteroidetes         Bacteroidia     Bacteroidales Porphyromonadaceae  unclassified
```

When you say "remove the (100)" from each string, I'm assuming you mean the `(93)`s, etc... as well, but if you *only* want the `(100)`s removed, you can use:

```
d3[] <- sapply(d3,function(x){
  gsub("\\(100\\)","",as.character(x))
})
##
> d3
        V1             V2                  V3                V4                 V5               V6
2 Bacteria Proteobacteria Gammaproteobacteria   Pseudomonadales   Pseudomonadaceae  Pseudomonas(98)
3 Bacteria  Bacteroidetes     Bacteroidia(93) Bacteroidales(93)   unclassified(93) unclassified(93)
4 Bacteria     Firmicutes             Bacilli   Lactobacillales   Streptococcaceae    Streptococcus
5 Bacteria Proteobacteria Gammaproteobacteria    Pasteurellales    Pasteurellaceae unclassified(68)
6 Bacteria Proteobacteria Gammaproteobacteria Enterobacteriales Enterobacteriaceae unclassified(90)
7 Bacteria  Bacteroidetes         Bacteroidia     Bacteroidales Porphyromonadaceae     unclassified
```